# PowerShell scheduled task

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a Windows scheduled task using PowerShell to run an .exe at logon of any user, then re-run it every minute and have it run every minute indefinitely.

```
$computer = $env:ComputerName
$taskName = "MyTask"
$L = New-ScheduledTaskAction –Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "$dropboxPath\request\Scripts\File_Permissions.ps1"
$T = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn
$P = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "$env:ComputerName\$adminname" -LogonType Password -RunLevel Highest
$S = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Action $L -Trigger $T -User $adminname -Password $adminpassword -Settings $S
$T.RepetitionInterval = (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1)
$T.RepetitionDuration = ([timespan]::MaxValue)
Set-ScheduledTask $taskName -Trigger $T
```

My script gives an error, it doesn't like the RepetitionInterval and RepetitionDuration.

Beed looking for ages on the internet and can't get this work. Here's another attempt which also fails:

```
$computer = $env:ComputerName
$L = New-ScheduledTaskAction –Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "$dropboxPath\request\Scripts\File_Permissions.ps1"
$T = @()
$T += New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn -User *
$T += New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1) -RepetitionDuration ([timespan]::MaxValue)
$P = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "$env:ComputerName\$adminname" -LogonType Password -RunLevel Highest
$S = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "MyTask" -Action $L -Trigger $T -User $adminname -Password $adminpassword -Settings $S
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have taken the above from the other user (4c74356b41 (thanks)) and changed it around a little, I now have this working as the final:

```
$computer = $env:ComputerName
$taskName = "MyTask"
$L = New-ScheduledTaskAction –Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "c:\request\Scripts\File_Permissions.ps1"
$T = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn
$P = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "$env:ComputerName\$adminname" -LogonType Password -RunLevel Highest
$S = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Action $L -Trigger $T -User $adminname -Password $adminpassword -Settings $S
$task = get-scheduledtask -TaskName $taskName
$task.Triggers.repetition.Interval = 'PT01M'
$task.Triggers.repetition.Duration = 'P1D'
$task | Set-ScheduledTask -User $adminname -Password $adminpassword
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you should use this:

```
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Action $L -Trigger $T -User $adminname -Password $adminpassword -Settings $S
$task = get-scheduledtask -TaskName $taskName
$task.Triggers.repetition.Duration = 'PT60M'
$task.Triggers.repetition.Interval = 'PT01M'
$task | Set-ScheduledTask
```

taken from [here](https://www.petri.com/creating-repeating-powershell-scheduled-jobs).